# Dimensionality of similarity matrix

Tags: correlation, covariance, matrix, similarities, high-dimensional

Below is a screen shot of a paper. 
The authors take a data-set $E\in R^{nxm}$. Here $n$ is the number of observations/samples/patients and $m$ is the number of genes/features. 
Preprocessing  converts $E$ to $E'$...SO far it is OK.

My confusion arises when the author defines a $similaity$ measure between two patients.  Each patient has $m$ fatures and there are $n$ patient. So a similarity (e.g covariance) between two patients , $e_i$ and $e_j$ , should consist of some transformation $T$ of  $e_i$ and $e_j$ like $T(e_i,e_j)$ and each $e_i$ and $e_j$ should contain $m$ elements. i.e. $e_i,e_j \in R^{1xm}$ and the similarity matrix between all patients should be $R^{nxn}$.

My confusion arises because in the paper, $e_i,e_j \in R^{nx1}$ and similarity matrix is $R^{mxm}$.

[image]

Comment: Can that be a typo? They clearly say that $i$ and $j$ are indices of patients, if there are $n$ patients then $K$ must be of dimension $n\times n$.

Comment: Also, it would help if you wrote which paper is that.